# Adding null object to SQLite

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, nsarray

I implemented `SQLite` in xcode. I have 2 columns. When the first column has a row, then the second one is set to `null`, and vice versa. I'm trying to go through both columns and check if it has an object at that index.

```
NSLog(@"%@ and %@", firstArray, secondArray); // It gives the right risults, but there aren't any null objects in any of them.
for (int i = 0; i < [firstArray count]; i++)
{
    if (![[firstArray objectAtIndex:i] length] && [[secondArray objectAtIndex:i] length]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have two issues.

First: There aren't any null objects in the rows, even though I set some to null. So what should I do to check if there is a null object, or if there's another way to add some kind null object that will actually add to the tables row?

Second: When I compile and run the app, it crashes with the error below. But when I remove the if statement, it works flawlessly.

```
-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbfeb53b0a0
2015-03-30 11:25:04.731 MyApp [610:15600] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbfeb53b0a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110874f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011050dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011087c04d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107d427c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107d3e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   MyApp                        0x000000010fec3b59 -[ViewController ingredientAction] + 889
6   MyApp                       0x000000010feba253 -[ViewController menuAction:] + 195
7   UIKit                               0x0000000110ea58be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
8   UIKit                               0x0000000110fac410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
9   UIKit                               0x00000001110269ea -[UISegmentedControl _setSelectedSegmentIndex:notify:animate:] + 570
10  UIKit                               0x0000000111028a0f -[UISegmentedControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 143
11  UIKit                               0x0000000111252540 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 9487
12  UIKit                               0x0000000110eeaff6 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
13  UIKit                               0x0000000110eebc23 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 667
14  UIKit                               0x0000000110eb89b1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
15  UIKit                               0x0000000110ec5a7d _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
16  UIKit                               0x0000000110ea1103 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107aa551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107a041d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011079fa54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011079f486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000114c759f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
22  UIKit                               0x0000000110ea4420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
23  MyApp                        0x000000010fec11b3 main + 115
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001122ad145 start + 1
25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

**Edit**

I put `@""` instead of `null` into the row. Then I change the if statement (in the for loop) to the following:

```
NSStirng *objectAtIndexFromArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [firstArray objectAtIndex:i]];
if ([objectAtIndexFromArray isEqualToString:@""])
{
    NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

I don't get any `NSLogs` of `Hello`.

Comment: What is the content of `firstArray` ?

Comment: I have 2 columns.. The first column is stored in `firstArray`, and the second column is in `secondArray`. I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty new to ios development, but I know that if you want to add null object to you data collection you have to use NSNULL class.

**NSArray can't hold nils, if you want to check if null, please use this code**

```
id object = myArray[0];// similar to [myArray objectAtIndex:0]

if(![object isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
    //do something if object is not equals to [NSNull null]
}
```

Comment: You're right, but I don't think I can do that with SQLite?

Comment: From documentation. The SQLite NULL is the term used to represent a missing value. A NULL value in a table is a value in a field that appears to be blank.

A field with a NULL value is a field with no value. It is very important to understand that a NULL value is different than a zero value or a field that contains spaces. Hope it will help you.

Comment: So if I pass all values to an `array`, then technically, I should get nill? because I don't get anything at those places, it just skips them.

Comment: As I understand when you're trying to write null to sqlite, in the db this field with will be blank, and when you then load data from db you will get nil.

Comment: I did an `NSLog`, and I didn't get a nill, it just skipped it. What I did was, I just put an empty string like: @"". Then when I checked if objectAtIdex:i isequealTo:@"" then do something. But the app crashesr.

Comment: The problem is in this line: [[firstArray objectAtIndex:i] length] there is no selector length. What you expect to get with this line?

Comment: I want to see weather it is a nil or not. But when I did an `nslog` of the array, I didn't see any nil objects, so instead of adding a nil, I put empty text in the row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74139/discussion-between-edison-and-sergstav).